# 3D Connexion mouse not working in Blender

Tags: interface, add-on

The 3D mouse works fine in SketchUp but not at all in Blender 2.79. I can't find a good reference to fix this. I need an exact and complete step by step approach because I feel like an idiot after trying other suggestions. I am using Windows 10.